# Search text column for certain strings and return the time in the cell, Excel

Tags: excel

I work in a hospital and need to keep track of how much time and when I spend that time in different areas. Clinical and Research. There are multiple things that count as clinical hours though they are not the same thing. In the picture CFW, Clinic, AMJ, etc count as clinical. Training, Research, lunch, data, r383, experiment are not needed to keep track of. It appears like this:

```
___   A ____        B     
1   8:30    Training
2   9:00    CFW
3   9:30    CFW
4   10:00   CFW
5   10:30   Clinic
6   11:00   Clinic
7   11:30   Research
8   12:00   Lunch
9   12:30   Data
10  1:00    AMJ
11  1:30    AMJ
12  2:00    AMJ
13  2:30    R383
14  3:00    Experiment
15  3:30    Experiment
16  4:00    Research
```

My end goal is to be able to have a list of text that I can search for, like "Clinic", and it tell me which times I was there and the total time spent, like 10:30-11:30 1 hour.

Clinic: 10:30-11:30
        1 Hour

So if I search all of the text phrases it would have the times spent there (beginning - end), and the sum total length of time. I have a separate sheet for each day of the week and ideally would like to be able to search through all 5 sheets at once and have all the days pop up all organized and such.

For example:
Monday
Clinic: 10:30-11:30
        1 Hour
AMJ: 1:00-2:30
     1.5 Hours
Tuesday
CFW: 9:00-10:30
     1.5 Hours
etc...

Sorry for my formatting. Let me know if I need to any more information. I'm not able to post the picture yet. Any ideas? Please and thank

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a VBA Macro on your Excel Spreadsheet that will go through each sheet, look for what value you want (e.g. "Clinic"), capture your times and calculate the elapsed.

You can refer to each sheet, and the cells in loops. Here is a shell to get you started.

```
Public Function elapsedTime (byval searchFor As String)
    Dim shIdx as Integer
    Dim rIdx as Integer
    Dim calc as Integer
    rIdx = 2
    For shIdx = 1 to 5
        While Sheets(shIdx).Range("A" + CStr(rIdx)).Value <> "" 
            If Sheets(shIdx).Range("B" + CStr(rIdx)).Value = searchFor Then
                Additional logic here to calculate your value and
                store it in "calc"...
            End If
            rIdx = rIdx + 1
        Wend
        rIdx = 2
    Next shIdx
    elapsedTime = calc
End Function
```